# System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, api, exception, timer, dispose

----- Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling---

Hi can any one help me to resolve this problem

```
public class RealTimeMessage : ControllerBase
{
    private IHubContext<MessageHub, IMessageHubClient> messageHub;
    private readonly JobbyContext _Context;
    private  TimerManager _timer;
    public RealTimeMessage(IHubContext<MessageHub, IMessageHubClient> _messageHub,JobbyContext C,TimerManager T)
    {
        messageHub = _messageHub;
        _Context = C;
        _timer = T;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("SendMessage")]
    public  async Task<IActionResult> SendRealTimeMessage()
    {

        if (!_timer.IsTimerStarted)
         await _timer.PrepareTimer( async()=>
            {
                var m = await _Context.message.ToListAsync(x=> x.IsRead==false);// **=> Error here**
                if (m.Count>0)
                {
                    await messageHub.Clients.All.SendMessageToUser(m);
                }
                

            });
        
        return Ok(new { Message = "Request Completed" });
        
    }
}

public class TimerManager
{
    private Timer? _timer;
    private AutoResetEvent? _autoResetEvent;
    private Func<Task>? _action;
    public DateTime TimerStarted { get; set; }
    public bool IsTimerStarted { get; set; }

    public   async Task PrepareTimer(Func<Task> action)
    {
        _action =  action;
        _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _timer = new  Timer(Execute, _autoResetEvent, 1000, 3000);
        TimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
        IsTimerStarted = true;
       
    }

    public async void Execute(object? stateInfo)
    {
        await _action();

        if ((DateTime.Now - TimerStarted).TotalSeconds > 10000)
        {
            IsTimerStarted = false;
                _timer.Dispose();

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the time the action runs, the request has already finished and the HttpContext is disposed.

Comment: Posting images of code, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. It will definitely put off people who might otherwise answer your question.

Comment: Also, it should just be "IsRead". "Readed" is not a word.

Comment: [Here's a helpful link](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) explaining why we prefer the code to be included as text instead of an image

Comment: thinx @Jonesopolis ... how can i fix this Error

Comment: thinx @JoelCoehoorn  the post is updated now

Comment: Thinx @Andrew Williamson

Comment: It's hard to say what the solution is without knowing what you are trying to achieve. Can you please describe what you _want_ the code to do?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson the code is a part of an API for Job portal that send unread message to the connected user,  i use SignalR for real time communication    , and the timer to get message from database every 3 seconds

Comment: Why do you have an endpoint to start the timer, and why does it stop after 10 seconds? Is that behaviour supposed to be per-user, or global for all users?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson The code is not yet completed, the end point to get UserId when user is connected and then send them their message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a significant change in how this works.

- When a user opens the site for the first time, it fetches all their unread messages
- Every time a message is sent, it is *always* broadcast via SignalR to the recipient

If the recipient is connected, they will receive the message immediately via SignalR. If they are not connected, they will receive it when they open the site. This will drastically simplify the implementation, and will reduce load on the database.